# Load vue-i18n messages before routes are loaded

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

I'm trying to make translatable routes using [vue-i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n).

The way I would like it to work is that the JSON files would have translations for specific route URLs.

e.g. `{ 'home_url': 'Home' }`
then in my routes, I would use something like this:

```
export default [
  { path: i18n.t('home_url'), name: 'home', component: Home }
]
```

The problem though is that the routes are loaded before i18n messages are imported.

Is there any way I could delay routes loading until i18n is ready?

**This is how I load my translations:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import store from '~/store'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: {}
})

/**
 * @param {String} locale
 */
export async function loadMessages (locale) {
  if (Object.keys(i18n.getLocaleMessage(locale)).length === 0) {
    const messages = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "lang-[request]" */ `~/lang/${locale}`)
    i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages)
  }

  if (i18n.locale !== locale) {
    i18n.locale = locale
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = locale
    document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', locale)
  }
}

;(async function () {
  await loadMessages(store.getters['lang/locale'])
})()

export default i18n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` import(/* webpackChunkName: "lang-[request]" */ `~/lang/${locale}`) `` is a Webpack Async Import, so it will be loaded after your main app script is loaded, not at the same time.

I will recommend two solution (pick the one that suits you better):

1. remove your `loadMessages` functions and load all Json-s synchronously. The app bundle will grow (all translations will be inside) but it will load them on the app start.
2. Delay router creation (`router = new Router(...)`) until all the locales are loaded (`loadMessages` finished).

Comment: I've tried #1 solution but it seems like routes are still loaded before messages.

Also, how would you suggest I delay the router creation? (#2 solution)

Comment: My bad, I was using `import` instead of require. Now it works. Thanks! But still interested to know what did you have in mind by delaying router creation.

Comment: You can create router (and mount Vue app) after `await loadMessages(store.getters['lang/locale'])` resolove, but to do that you have to make more changes. You could try to call `loadMessages` in the file where your are mounting the Vue app.

Comment: I've tried that and many other loadMessages scenarios but it didn't work. Anyway, will stick with the #1. Thanks again.